# Problems with my interpolation inplementation

Tags: movement, interpolation

When I interpolate my sprite's movement (code below), I'm curious as to whether the part where I actually apply the interpolation to the sprite's current X position (in my render call) is correct.

This is why I'm asking....

In all the examples I can find, it is pretty much like this:

```
         render(float interpolation){

            //This example shows interpolation for X axis only.

            interpolatedPosX = spriteGridX+(SpriteXVelocity*dt)*interpolation;
            spriteScreenPosX = interpolationPosX * screenWidth;

            drawSprite(spriteScreenX, spriteScreenY);  
         }
```

Now, for me, this only works when the sprite is moving right(or down for sprites moving along the Y Axis, the example above uses X movement).

I have to do something like this:

```
render(float interpolation){

            //This example shows interpolation for X axis only.

     if (sprite.isGoingRight){
            interpolatedPosX = spriteGridX+(SpriteXVelocity*dt)*interpolation;
     }

     else if (sprite.isGoingLeft){
            interpolatedPosX = spriteGridX-(SpriteXVelocity*dt)*interpolation;
     }

     spriteScreenPosX = interpolationPosX * screenWidth;

     drawSprite(spriteScreenX, spriteScreenY);

 }
```

The above makes sense to me, as you add to the position to go right and subtract to go left, but I ask because I can't find an example that shows this behaviour, so I don't know if either the examples just aren't going into this detail and assume the reader will know this or I've got this wrong?

Any help would be appreciated as I'm only just starting to get to grips with interpolation!

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {


        //Set/Re-set loop back to 0 to start counting again
        loops=0;

        while(System.currentTimeMillis() > nextGameTick && loops < maxFrameskip){

        SceneManager.getInstance().getCurrentScene().updateLogic();
        nextGameTick+=skipTicks;
        timeCorrection += (1000d/ticksPerSecond) % 1;
        nextGameTick+=timeCorrection;
        timeCorrection %=1;
        loops++;
        tics++;

     }

        interpolation = (float)(System.currentTimeMillis() + skipTicks - nextGameTick) / (float)skipTicks; 

        render(interpolation);
}
```

**Applying interpolation**

```
            render(float interpolation){

            //This example shows interpolation for X axis only.  Y position (spriteScreenY is assumed to be valid)
            interpolatedPosX = spriteGridX+(SpriteXVelocity*dt)*interpolation;
            spriteScreenPosX = interpolationPosX * screenWidth;

            drawSprite(spriteScreenX, spriteScreenY);           


        }
```

Comment: I have edited your question title to better reflect the question body. The words "sprite movement" are irrelevant, because you ask about generic interpolation that is applicable to objects, sprites, billboards, 2D, 3D, etc. The word "problem" is optional, it is clear that you would not have posted the question if you did not had the problem in the first place ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your branches for `sprite.isGoingRight` and `sprite.isGoingLeft` are completely identical.

```
 if (sprite.isGoingRight){
        interpolatedPosX = spriteGridX+(SpriteXVelocity*dt)*interpolation;
 }

 else if (sprite.isGoingLeft){
        interpolatedPosX = spriteGridX+(SpriteXVelocity*dt)*interpolation;
 }
```

Secondly, you don't need to branch, because `SpriteXVelocity` should be a signed value, that is if the object is moving right, the value is positive, and if left - negative.

Fixing these two issues should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, explanation would be appreciated :)

Comment: You can have my upvote: your answer makes sense to me and is not just good advice but definitely proposes an answer to the problem within the code the person gave.

Comment: Oops - that was a typo - I've now corrected it.  Indeed, that's what I was missing, I wasn't changing it (negating it) depending on the direction of movement - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First a tip: Get hold of a decent vector/matrix library that you feel comfortable using. Saves a lot of typing and makes the code much more readable

Here is an example code (not tested)

```
class Sprite{
    public:
        Vec2d position; //Where are you now?
        Vec2d target; //Where do you want to go?
        float speed=2.5f; //How fast do you want to move(pixels per second)
public:
        void update(float secondsSinceLastUpdate){
            Vec2d diff=target-position;//The vector from your current position to your target position
            Vec2d direction=diff.normalized(); //Directional vector from current to target position
            Vec2d velocity= direction*speed*secondsSinceLastUpdate;//How to move for this update
            position+=velocity;//Update position
    }

    void render(Canvas c){
        /*
        Your rendering code gores here
        c.drawSprite(sprite,position);

        TIP: update and render can be called separately.

        Usually you call update() and render() once for every frame.
        Sometimes, is your game is "hidden" you can get away with calling just the update().

        Also if the secondsSinceLastUpdate gets too big, you can call update() several times per frame, effectively keeping the game state stable even when dropping frames.

    }
}
```

EDIT: I just realized you are probably using Java instead of C++. My code is pseudo C++, and you will have to adapt it to Java (no operator overloading available there yet). that means that you will probably do something like diff=target.minus(position); instead of diff=target-position; etc.